# Making a Chest for VR Game with Hinge - Now I need sound

Tags: unity, virtual-reality, hinge-joint

I am trying to make a litte RPG Game for VR (openXR and Hurricane VR framework in Unity)

The chest works now, but I would like to have an opening and closing sound. Because I dont use an animation for the chest, I have some trouble to implement this.

Any tips how I can do it? I use the Hinge script on the chest. Maybe I can do something with angle? I already tried a few things, but they sound wonky. Maybe someone has an better idea.

Comment: Is your definition of opening/ closing sound the effect that should be played when you open/ close it or when the state of the chest is fully opened/ closed?

Comment: What were the things you tried and in what "wonky" way did they sound different than you expected them to?

Comment: @Zibelas - No, more like playing during opening and closing. Like a rusty hinge sound.

Comment: @Philipp I tried to play it once the velocity was changed and tried to play the sound when the hinge.angle.magnitute was greater than 2. But that is not good enough. The sound should play when I open it relative to the angle (sorry, English is not my native language)

Comment: A real door/ chest makes different sounds depending on how fast you move it. Even my well oiled door makes sound if I just move it at the right speed. Having a sound right as you start moving it feels odd, it should move a certain distance at a certain speed before you start playing. Maybe the easiest to get realistic feedback would be to search for a door that makes noises and observe it. Different speeds = different sounds and some of them produce none at all. Once you know how they are produced from the real thing, transfer that knowledge to your chest

Comment: Have you tried having a sound clip that corresponds to opening the complete distance and then playing a section of the clip proportional to the start and end angle of the motion?

Comment: @GaleRazorwind Yes, I tried, but did not get it to work.